# How to configure a Java - Eclipse project for using log4j with Java 9+ modules

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, java-module

Since my Java skills are a bit rusty I am not sure how to setup / configure log4j.
In older Java projects I downloaded log4j and put log4j-core and log4j-api into the classpath.

However I am getting now the error `The import org.apache cannot be resolved`

I noticed that in the newly created project there is a new file called `module-info.java`
My understanding of that file is to make distribution lighter (among other benfits)

On the [Apache - Log4j Runtime Dependencies - Website](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/runtime-dependencies.html) I see that "As of version 2.10.0 the Log4j API is a Java module" so I tried adding the following lines to the `modeule-info.java` file:

```
requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
```

resulting in

```
module uploadTestFileGeneration {
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
}
```

However now I have the error `org.apache.logging.log4j cannot be resolved to a module` (within the module file)

In my Java Class where I want to use the logger the error changed from `The import org.apache cannot be resolved` to `The import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager cannot be resolved`

**So my question is how to setup an Eclipse Java project in order to use the log4j2?**

Comment: If you have placed the jars on the modulepath, can you share what JARs have you placed? I can confirm using `Maven` and a dependency `<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId> <version>2.13.1</version> </dependency>`, that I am able to compile `requires org.apache.logging.log4j;` in the descriptor. In a different IDE(intelliJ) though, but that only indicates chances of a bug or incompatibility in Eclipse.

Comment: I added log4j-api-2.13.1.jar and log4j-core-2.13.1.jar into the module path. I do not use maven